# How to Get Shapefile to Fit Extent of Polygon

Tags: shapefile

I have a shapefile that I am trying to convert to raster.  I am trying to select one field of the shapefile using ArcMap, and then convert it to raster.  I then want to use that raster and combine it with a polygon shapefile and want it to only fit within the boundaries of the polygon shapefile.  Specifically, what I am trying to do is select aggregate travel cost from a shapefile, combine it with the U.S. states shapefile, and do a contour map where the legend colors will not go outside the boundaries of the U.S.